# HTML & CSS - display a partial marquee box

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a small or "partial" marquee box inside a container. Basically I would like to display the 4 inner corners. Something similar to the following: I'm wondering how could I do it? Any help is appreciated.

```
  +--------------------------------------------+  ---> this is main container
  |  +--                                  --+  |
  |  |                                      |  |
  |                                            |
  |                                            |
  |                                            |
  |                                            |
  |                                            |
  |  |                                      |  |
  |  +--                                  --+  |
  +--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Do you have an image example of how it should look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id='the_container' style='border: 1px solid #000; width:90%; height:90%; top: 5%; left: 5%; position: absolute;'>
            <div id='corner_t_l' style='border-top: 1px dashed #000; border-left: 1px dashed #000; top: 10px; left: 10px; width: 30px; height: 30px; position: absolute;'></div>
            <div id='corner_t_r' style='border-top: 1px dashed #000; border-right: 1px dashed #000; top: 10px; right: 10px; width: 30px; height: 30px; position: absolute;'></div>
            <div id='corner_b_r' style='border-bottom: 1px dashed #000; border-right: 1px dashed #000; bottom: 10px; right: 10px; width: 30px; height: 30px; position: absolute;'></div>
            <div id='corner_b_l' style='border-bottom: 1px dashed #000; border-left: 1px dashed #000; bottom: 10px; left: 10px; width: 30px; height: 30px; position: absolute;'></div>        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/vKZzD/

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```
    <div style='padding: 15px'>
     <div style='background: url(...)'></div>
    </div>
```

? If the height and width is unknown, you can use approaches used for generating rounded corners on 4 divs for example

Comment: Yeah that would work, however I was looking for actually doing it purely using borders & divs on each corner. Would that be feasible?